# IRS accepted my e-file but the IRS website can't find a record of it

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

I e-filed my 2020 taxes seven days ago and it was accepted by the IRS. However, when I visit the IRS's "Get Refund Status" website, it cannot find my return. I have never had this occur in years past. I tried calling the IRS but the call volume is so large that it is not accepting any calls. I also reached out to H&R Block - I used its software to file - and the CSR can't help since they do not have access to the IRS system. Should I be concerned? I am considering printing out my return and mailing it in "just in case".

Comment: It took more than 10 days for me to appear. Be patient. They are overloaded.

Answer (score 2):

Don't print out your tax return and send it by mail to IRS; it will just get rejected as a duplicate. If you have a receipt from H&R Block that your electronically filed return has been accepted by the IRS, print *that* out and save it in your (paper) tax file if you wish, along with whatever else you have in that file (print-out of return, paper copies of W2, 1099, charitable donations receipts, etc).

An article in The Washington Post a couple of days ago said that the IRS had more than 7 million returns that had been received by the IRS but were still not processed (and thus not showing on their website), as compared to only 2 million returns on the same date last year. Separately, there was a glitch in the "Where's My Refund?" software (now apparently fixed) which prevented processed applications from showing to taxpayers when they checked. It doesn't help that the IRS is distracted due to the rush of getting the stimulus payments out ASAP. So, it is not too surprising that the OP cannot see his refund on the IRS website. It is only 8 days ago that he e-filed, and presumably his return is still waiting in the processing queue. As to what will happen to his third stimulus payment since he has changed banks, well, I assume that the IRS will try to use the bank where he got his previous stimulus payments if it has not processed his 2020 return by now.

Comment: How can I confirm that the IRS does have my return? I'm concerned that I won't receive my refund. I never received the second stimulus check (switched banks) so I was expecting it with my refund.

Comment: The second stimulus checks have not been sent out as yet. If you got the first via direct deposit into your old account, there might be an issue since you have switched banks.

Comment: I am referring to the second check, not the third one that was just signed. I had to claim the second stimulus on my tax return since the IRS has incorrect bank information for me.  This is why I'm anxious that the website can't seem to locate my filing

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same issue as the OP, except I filed mine through TurboTax on February 11, and there's still no record of it with the IRS, even though I did get an email confirmation from TurboTax that it had been accepted.
When I finally did reach someone at the IRS, they said they couldn't see it frmo their side, whatever that means, and when they tried to transfer me to someone else, the call was cut off.  I haven't been able to get ahold of anyone since.  All I can do at this point is wait a few more weeks and see what happens.
For the record, my latest stimulus payment showed up at my bank overnight last night and was posted this morning.  SHOCKINGLY quick for the U.S. government!